# make text in nested td center vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has three `td`'s. Inside the first and last `td` there are nested tables. The last has lines and lines of text, while the first will be just one or two lines. The middle is just one line of text. How can I make the first table have its second row fill up the remaining horizontal space so that one line of text is centered horizontally, lining up with the free floating text in the second `td`. I've tried wrapping it in a `div` with a constant height, but that didn't do anything. I'm not sure what else I can do.

Desired result:

```
+------------+------------+------------+
|    blah    |   bleh     |    blet    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|            |            |    asdf ds |
|            |            |  sdff sdf  |
|    blah    |    blah    |  sadf sd f |
|            |            | sdf sdfs df|
|            |            |    dss dsd |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/pifanoja/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

If the site doesn't need to be responsive and you know the height of the table you could add a CSS height/min-height property - otherwise I think you'd have to leverage some JavaScript to calculate the height of the table and then apply that value to the table.

http://jsbin.com/pifanoja/6/edit

```
.less_text table {
    height:140px
}
```